# How to formulate $\min \|X-z^T\mathbf{1}^T\|$ as a least-squares problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, least-squares

Suppose $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, i.e., there are $n$ columns. Some of columns of $X$ are known, some of columns of $X$ are unknown (variables). Suppose I have $$\min_{x,z} \|X-z\mathbf{1}^T\|^2_2$$

where $z\in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \mathbf{1}\in \mathbb{R}^n$. So the optimization variables are those unknown columns $x$ and $z$.

How to show that this can be written as a least-squares problem? And what is the (geometric) meaning of $z$?

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a least-squares problem for the standard interpretation of $\|\cdot\|_2$ for matrices—the _induced_ 2-norm; i.e., the spectral norm. It is if you change it to $\|\cdot\|_F$, the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks, I will check this. If that is a Frobenius norm, how to transform that to a least-squares problem? a hint please and thanks!

Comment: I believe mathreadler is on the right track already. By converting the problem to a vector, it _is_ valid to use the 2-norm.

Comment: I see what you meant now. ;) Yes it will work for this problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First vectorize $X$ and $z$ together in some way, for example $$\text{vec}(X,z) = [\text{vec}(X),\text{vec}(z)]^T$$I will assume this vectorization (first orders all elements of $X$ and then all elements of $z$). Then build
$$A=[M_I,M_{-1^T}]$$
Where $M$ is matrix representation of "multiplied with" subscript.
Here you can use [Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) to your help.
Now you want to minimize
$$\|A \text{vec}(X,z)\|_2^2$$
To encode the $X$ values being known, just add a term like this:
$$\|C(\text{vec}(X,z)-p)\|_2^2$$
Where $C$ is diagonal matrix encoding which values are known (large positive values if known, $\epsilon>0$ otherwise), and $p$ vector contains those values.

Comment: I am still confused about $M_I$ and $M_{-1^T}$. And should the last line be $\|A-vec(X,z)\|_2^2$?  In my original problem, some columns of $X$ are known, some unknown; how do you deal with this in your answer?  Thanks!

Comment: The $A$ matrix will automatically do the - between $X$ and $z$ term when you multiply with it. Ok I will add info for X values being known.

Comment: You say for the X values being known, add that term. Where do you add that term?

Comment: @Denny it was unlucky formulation. I rewrote the sentence.